# How to Set TabIndex on Press Enter Tab in MVC3 Using Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

my Problem is that, when i press the enter Button in any textbox or place in form the cursor Automatically go to create button and press it..... i working in mvc3, so please tell me any solution....

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the [`.keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event of the form and cancel it if it was Enter:

```
$(function() {
    // subscribe to the keypress event of the form
    $('form').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            // if Enter was pressed cancel the default action and
            // prevent the form from submitting
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @LakhbirChandel, if this post helped you solve the issue you were having make sure you [mark it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.